# Best Practice to Manage Multiple Newsletter Databases

Tags: mysql, database, e-commerce

I have two separate newsletter databases right now. One is a simple opt-in where a customer can just give their email address to receive our mailings, and the other is a full-blown customer account database (username, password, address, order history, etc.). Both end up getting basically the same newsletters (we do some segmentation and dynamic content where possible). Additionally, I should mention that the opt-in table has some one-off columns where different marketing initiatives have gathered data about the contact (where the contact registered [online/offline] and what promotion it was apart of, their mailing address if we have it, etc.).

I've had these two lists set up for years, but it is getting harder and harder to manage as a customer moves from a simple opt-in to creating an account, they update their email address, etc.. Once the user creates the account, it would make sense that they'll manage their newsletter settings from in there. But sometimes an existing customer enters their email address in the opt-in (or vice versa) and it starts getting complicated to manage the duplicates. We also have to deal with a lot of duplicate data between the two databases (and going across multiple databases, not just tables, is a challenge).

Adding to the complications, we send our newsletter using a third party service. We have some processes that run every-so-often that will do some two-way syncing, so I have to do some juggling each time to determine which database I pull changes from/push changes to, which source was updated last, etc.. If the contact is moving from the opt-in list to the customer list, I have to push changes, deactivate the old relationship; if they added themselves to the opt-in and we already have their email in the other database, I set a flag to ignore them -- it's all a headache.

Now this has to be a pretty common situation. Almost every ecommerce site I go to has at least two distinct lists like this. My question is how are they handling it? What's the best practice?

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Use two different tables in the same database (which is pretty close to how I'm doing it now). This allows me to continue to keep things separate and organized, but efficiently check both lists as the same time for conflicting/duplicate information. I still have many of the same problems (moving the relationship or defining a "master record", duplicate data, propagating changes, etc.), but it should simplify a few things at least.
2. Create a single table (call it NewsletterContacts or something) for all contacts to share. Opt-in users would probably be added directly, but entries from the customer account table would would have to be synced. There are a number of downsides to this too, though. Any change to the customer account table would have to be pushed to NewsletterContacts before it could be pushed to our email software. I'd have some very mixed content in that database -- some records would have an address and source and such, others would just have an email address, and then others would point to a customer account table that would have all types of other information.

**TL,DR:** How do you manage two separate newsletter lists when you know there will be duplicates?